# Integral of a function and limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $f$ be a positive and continuous function on $[0,1]$. It can be shown there exists, for every natural number $n$, a real natural number $m(n)\in [0,1]$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=
\int_0^{m (n)}f(x)\,dx+\int_{1-m(n)}^1 f(x)\,dx
$$
then what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}nm(n)$?

First of all I couldn't prove there exists some $m(n)$ but just took an example of the function $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. But they are not positive they are just non negative. But doing this I got the limit as 0.5. Can anyone tell me how to prove the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof. Since $f$ is positive and continuous, all integrals are $>0$. Thus, we can write
$$n\,m(n)=\frac{\int_0^1f(x)dx}{\frac{1}{m(n)}\int_0^{m(n)}f(x)dx+\frac{1}{m(n)}\int_{1-m(n)}^1f(x)dx}$$
Now, we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}m(n)=0$, so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{m(n)}\int_0^{m(n)}f(x)dx=f(0),\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{m(n)}\int_{1-m(n)}^1f(x)dx=f(1).$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\, m(n)=\frac{1}{f(0)+f(1)}\int_0^1f(x)dx.$$

Comment: Why shoul limit m(n) be 0

Comment: Because $\lim\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$.

Comment: And the limit of $m(n)$ exists since $f$ is positive and continuous and this implies that $m(n)$ is decreasing. Since $m(n)$ is bounded from bellow, it converges by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: How did you calculate $f(0)$ and $f(1)$

Comment: @user312254 L'hospital rule.

Comment: Hey thanx spenser for the results thanku very much

Comment: @user312254 You are welcome.